# Segmentation fault when running vlc application in yocto build

Tags: vlc, yocto

I compiled vlc using bitbake vlc whenever i try to open vlc either via command line or via vlc application icon i get the following error

```
root@iWave-G15:~# vlc -vvv
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.2.2 Weatherwax
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: Copyright �© 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: configured with ../vlc-2.2.2/configure  '--build=x86_64-linux' '--host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi' '--target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi' '--prefix=/usr' '
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[001450d0] core libvlc warning: cannot read /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat: No such file or directory
[001450d0] core libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: have you extracted the stack trace from the core?

Comment: how to extract stack trace from the core?

Comment: easiest way is to install gdb